# Need Help on Next.JS and Safari Browser Cache Problem

Tags: next.js, browser-cache, cache-control

Problem detail: I've been troubled with this issue for a week til now. I've also posted on github but no one answered. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45937

This is a bug with getStaticProps with fallback: true onSafari + MacOS Ventura or Safari+ iOS 16.3

It works fine in Chrome:
Prefetch URLs return 200 once then next time they always return 304:

On Safari:
Prefetch URLs always return header 200. And the caching doesn't work, it still needs to fetch again when I click the link.

I'm glad to give away a beefsteak meal to someone who can solve this issue.

I've tested on localhost on safari and it resulted the problem same as always. no cache returned.

Expected Behavior
Safari should work the same as Chrome. First time http status should be 200, the 2nd time is 304.